# Injecting javascript to each tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome browser extension which will inject a fixed js script in active tab.

As a beginner in javascript don't know how to do it. I tried to follow [this](https://gist.github.com/danharper/8364399) tutorial. Copy-pasting the source code didn't worked in my browser.

However the javascript code I wrote for my extension - if I add that script in a html page and run that on browser - it works fine. That means no error in the script. But when I add that script in a file to be injected alike the tutorial - nothing happens.

There is no console output about "something error". Maybe I'm missing something or this should be done in another way(s). Help needed.

Here are the files for the tutorial link provided above.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Injecta",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Injecting stuff",
  "homepage_url": "http://danharper.me",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Inject!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

inject.js

```
(function(){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.position = 'fixed';
    div.style.top = 0;
    div.style.right = 0;
    div.textContent = 'Injected!';
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    alert('inserted self... giggity');
})();
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib,{
        file: 'inject.js'
    });
});
```

I loaded the files in chrome as unpacked extension. Then in a new tab, I opened [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). As per the code, there should be the word "Injected!", but there was nothing like this.

**What I am trying to do** is if the loaded page has javascript like this:

```
<script>
var a=1;
</script>
```

And my inject.js

```
var b=2;
```

Then after loading the page's script should be:

```
<script>
var a=1;
var b=2;
</script>
```

**For this I wrote the following files **

My manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Injector",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description":"Inject some code",
  "permissions":[
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ],

  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action":{
    "default_title": "Injector",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "background.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

My background.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body> Injector
    </body>
</html>
```

My background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: 'inject.js'
    });
});
```

My inject.js

```
function test(){
    var b=2;
    console.log(b);
}

test();
```

Comment: I am not aiming to change a variable instead want to inject code in a file. The file contains jQuery objects and functions.

Comment: What to do to achieve my target?

Comment: It was just for examine.

Comment: I tried the first one which came with the tutorial mentioned in the question. Didn't work.

Comment: This question may be about an [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). Inserting scripts into the page context is something that is only needed if you are wanting to directly interact with the JavaScript that already exists on the page (and a small subset of other reasons). While it is quite possible that what you are ultimately trying to achieve requires this (not just this text/example), you may not need to do so. Please describe in more detail what it is you are attempting to achieve. Note: This is also more complex. You may want to try an easier first test extension.

Comment: I am trying to change the keyboard input for all the textarea in a page. I have script that can do if that code is a part of the page ( that page I wrote to test the code and works fine). Now for other webpages I need to inject that part of javascript. Want to create an extension to do that.